# Text looks different on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am making a simple website for a friend and I want it to look nice on both PC and mobile, but on mobile it looks different - all the text seems shifted up or all the `<div>`s seem shifted down.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

[How it looks on my PC using Chrome's mobile view thing, how it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaqR8.png)

[How it looks on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoGtZ.jpg)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your code so we can see what's happening, but my first guess - if you're using media queries, are any of them targeting `max-device-width`/`min-device-width` instead of `max-width`/`min-width`? If so, change them to get a consistent experience.